# r - after filtering all my values become na

Tags: r, filter

Please help me!
I have quite big data set containing bank accounts

[image]

It is organised in a following way:

> `V1` - register number of a bank
>
> `V2` - date of account value record
>
> `V3` - account number
>
> all remaining `V`-s are for values themselves (in cur, metals, etc)

I need to make a filter through account numbers, remaining everything in the table, but for specific acc numbers. Here is the code I use:

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".txt")

datalist = lapply(filelist, function(x)read.table(x, header=FALSE, sep = ";")) 

all_data = do.call("rbind", datalist) 

r_d <- rename(all_data, c("V1"="Number", "V2"="Dates", "V3"="Account"))
r_d$Account <- as.character(r_d$Account)
f_d <- filter(all_data, r_d$Account >= 42301 & r_d$Account <= 42315 |
    r_d$Account >= 20202 & r_d$Account <= 20210 |
    r_d$Account == 98010 | r_d$Account == 98015)
```

The problem is that the output of this code is a table containing only `NA`s, everything becomes `NA`, even though those acc numbers exist, and I am absolutely sure in that.

If I use Account in filter instead of `r_d$Account`, R writes me that object Account does not exist. Which I also do not understand.

Please, correct me.

Comment: If the filter function you are using is the one from package `dplyr`, try removing the "r_d$" and just write Account without quotes like so: `filter(all_data, Account >= 42301 ... `

Comment: In this case, though @PLapointe's suggestion is valid, the code works identically; it will not work the same when your mid-pipe functions change the data.frame. However, since this is not a [reproducible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), we're unable to do much. Problems: (1) image of data vice `dput(head(data,n=10))`; (2) use of `rename` is not correct; (3) use of `filter` is ill-advised; (4) you show `filelist` but is it at all relevant here?

Comment: BTW: based on your treating of account numbers as ordinal vice categorical, some of your filtering will benefit from the `%in%` and `dplyr::between` functions, arguably making your filter much easier to read.

Comment: If I use Account in filter instead of r_d$Account, R writes me that object Account does not exist. Which I also do not understand.

Comment: Why rename function is not correct? I then guess that the problem starts here, R does not understand what to filter and this is why gives me NA-s only, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code. The reason you are getting `NA`s is that you are passing `NULL`s all over the place. Did you ever look at `r_d$Account`? When you see problems in your code, you should start by going things piece-meal step-by-step, and in this case you'll see that `r_d$Account` gives you `NULL`. Why? Because you did not rename the columns correctly. `colnames(r_d)` will be revealing.

First, `rename` either does non-standard evaluation with *un-quoted* arguments, or `rename_` takes a vector of `character`=`character` pairs. These might work (I can't know for certain, since I'm not about to transcribe your image of data ... please provide copyable output from `dput` next time!):

```
# non-standard evaluation
rename(all_data, Number=V1, Dates=V2, Account=V3)

# standard-evaluation #1:
rename_(all_data, Number="V1", Dates="V2", Account="V3")

# standard-evaluation #2
rename_(all_data, .dots = c("Number"="v1", "Dates"="V2", "Account"="V3"))
```

From there, if you step through your code, you should see that `r_d$Account` is no longer `NULL`.

Second, is there a reason you create `r_d` but still reference `all-data`? There are definitely times when you need to do this kind of stuff; here is not one of them, it is too prone to problems (e.g., if the row-order or dimensions of one of them changes).

Third, because you convert `$Account` to `character`, it is really inappropriate to use inequality comparisons. Though it is certainly legal to do so (`"1" < "2"` is `TRUE`), it will run into problems, such as `"11" < "2"` is also `TRUE`, and `"3" < "22"` is `FALSE`. I'm not saying that you should avoid conversion to string; I think it is appropriate. Your use of *account ranges* is perplexing: an account number should be categorical, not ordinal, so selecting a *range* of account numbers is illogical.

Fourth, even assuming that account numbers *should* be ordinal and ranges make sense, your use of `filter` can be improved, but only if you either (a) accept that comparisons of stringified-numbers is acceptable (`"3" > "22"`), or (b) keep them as integers. First, you should not be referencing `r_d$` within a NSE dplyr function. (**Edit**: you also need to group your logic with parentheses.) This is a literal translation from your code:

```
f_d <- filter(r_d, (Account >= 42301 & Account <= 42315) |
    (Account >= 20202 & Account <= 20210) |
    Account == 98010 | Account == 98015)
```

You can make this perhaps more readable with:

```
f_d <- filter(r_d,
              Account %in% c(98010, 98015) |
                between(Account, 42301, 42315) |
                between(Account, 20202, 20210)
              )
```

Perhaps a better way to do it, assuming `$Account` is `character`, would be to determine which accounts are appropriate based on some other criteria (open date, order date, something else from a different column), and once you have a vector of account numbers, do

```
filter(r_d,
       Account %in% vector_of_interesting_account_numbers)
```

Comment: Got a lot new useful info from your answer! Another problem appeared:( R shows only account numbers 98010 and 98015, but it skips all info between  42301, 42315 and 20202 and 20210:( Don't you why?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see your comment! With a big pleasure I will do it! Where is this Accept button?)

Comment: To the (upper-)left of the answer, immediately under the "up/down-vote" arrows. (Only the user who asked the question can see it.)